# Textbox which autocompletes with previous entries ASP.NET web application visual basic

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want a text box which, once something has been entered, has the option of dropping down to display the last 10 or so previous entries. 
I am in visual studio 2010 with visual basic.

The only property that seems to be related to it is AutoCompleteType and this doesn't seem to meet the requirement.

Comment: Just apply autocomplete="on" to your textbox. It's a dom property which is supporting by multiple browsers. <input autocomplete="on"/>

Comment: Autocomplete is browser based it's not application based. Is this a situation where the user will type the same thing in multiple times within the textbox?

Comment: Yes. The text box will take a 6 digit number (like an id) and people are often using the same three or four, so having the drop down to just pick one of the numbers they've entered recently will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want cannot be accomplished without extra implementation. There are some ways to do this.

1. You can save previous entries to database and give these entries to autocompletebox as datasource through codebehind.
2. You can save previous entries as browser cookie and get these cookies and give these to autocompletebox as datasource through javascript.